# Should DreamWeaver be in my front-end workflow?

Tags: workflow, dreamweaver, frontend

I am looking to speed up time to develop website layouts. So I am wondering if using  DreamWeaver for layouts is useful - efficient. I am looking at purchasing this software, so, I had a few questions.

I am very comfortable coding HTML, CSS and JavaScript(jQuery) by hand in either PHPDesigner or Notepad++. Most of the time for layouts I use FireFox and Firebug to see results in real time, and then check if it works across different browsers.

I want to know the opinion of people who have worked on the front-end:

- I feel code validation is important but not the end of the world(as my priorities) - I do however like to change my code often by hand. Does the output from this software let you do this?(compare to the html/css that micorsoft word vomits - Does this software do a similar thing?)
- Is this software used as a primary design tool by people who can code by hand and does it actually improve efficiency? or is it just for newbies?

I understand the Adobe family of products work really well with each other but I am trying to understand is if DreamWeaver really deserves to be in the front-end workflow(if you are proficient coding by hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you work with HTML/CSS/Javascript enough, it isn't difficult to "code by hand" but it is important to remember that front-end developers also code with their eyes, as well.  There is a lot going on up front that depends entirely on the code that runs on the client and you want to use an editor that helps you organize your code and, more importantly, gives you visibility into the challenges presented by complicated CSS and adhering to web standards.

If front-end coding was nothing more than pushing around angle brackets then notepad and repeatedly pressing F5 would be enough.  A great web editor will present the structure of your code in a meaningful way and all of your HTML, CSS, and Javascript takes on a complete feel.

You want a professional editor that will allow you to:

- Understand CSS inheritance
- Run visual diagnostics
- Debug across different browsers
- Create modern layouts/designs that are faithfully represented

I haven't used Dreamweaver in a few years but, these days, I'm really enjoying [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx).  It is not the FrontPage mess of yesteryears - it is a serious tool for web design and I urge you to take a close look.  The code is clean and smart and it certainly gives you the option of using its tools to build a site or you can code everything 100% by hand.  Don't forget, the key is not deciding which editor is best for coding by hand.  The thing you should be looking for is which editor makes you a better developer.

Regardless of whether or not you're a Microsoft, LAMP, or other platform person, Expression Web is a great tool for front-end developers.

Comment: Yea, its seems pretty neat. Photoshop to Fireworks(needs a plugin) to DreamWeaver can be done without tables and absolute positioning and love the way it handles styles and I think my speed will improve once I get used to the GUI.

Comment: If you live in the Adobe world of products then staying close to Adobe ecosystem is the way go.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Dreamweaver for a few years now. While I initially used some of it's code generators, these days I pretty much spend my time in the code widow coding by hand and viewing the output in the browser.  The design window is nice for simple coding as it will build the html for you.  However, I did have problems getting the right insertion point to edit it.  For example, it might place my update before and end tag when I wanted it to be after it.  That led my to switch to the coding window to be sure.

I do like the fact that it opens all included files specified in the file you originally opened.  I also use it's site views to synchronize my changes to the production server.  I'm sure I could take advantage of other features if I bother to learn them. I haven't used any tools besides FrontPage so I can't compare.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing that happened to me was learing about [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and then after about [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/). I was using notepad++ for everything, but now im doing everything with eclipse and aptana as plugin for eclipse. Just my 2 cents. Oh and its [free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

Answer (score 0):

Primarily I do use Adobe Dreamweaver when working on websites. It is a pretty nice tool to use along with Adobe Photoshop for any graphic designs that I create.

Also, I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for Web Application Development (i.e Console apps, Web Apps, Silverlight, etc.). VS is a little different from DW but its still a nice tool for development projects.

Alison, I looked a preview of Expression Web and may check it out. It may aid as an impressive tool for my front-end dvelopment work. I also tried [Microsoft Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) when designing Silverlight applications. It does remind you of how Expression Web looks and feels